# Que condicion o bucle usar

Tags: c

como hago para que si mi condición no cumple me vuelva a preguntar hasta que haya ingresado correctamente

ejemplo: El usuario tenia que ingresar dígitos que estén entre el 1-12, no me da esto

```
void pedir_num(int num){

int num1;
printf("escriba un numero del 1-12");
scanf("%i", num1);
int rango;
for ( rango=0; rango<=12; rango++)  {

    do {        
        printf("Introdusca correctamente");
} while (num1 != rango);
```

}

```
int main(){

int num;

pedir_num(&num);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Yo quitaría el bucle `do-while` de dentro del método. Y lo añades al `main`, y dentro del bucle llamas al método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- No es necesario mandar un parámetro debido a que la variable que rompe el ciclo la usas en la función (Sólo es para no perder el origen de las variables es opcional)
2.- Cuando usas scanf se utiliza &
3.- Nunca cierras el for e incluso hasta lo combinas con do-while, el cual no es necesario meter dentro de otro ciclo porque aunque este dentro del rango te preguntara 12 veces

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    pedir_num();
    return 0;
}
void pedir_num(){
    int num1;
    do{
        printf("escriba un numero del 1-12\n");
        scanf("%i", &num1);
    }while(num1 <= 0 || num1 > 12);
    printf("Tu numero esta dentro del rango");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa un do...while():

```
void pedir_num(int num){
  int num1;
  int cumple = 1;
  do
  {
    if (cumple == 0)
    {
      printf("El valor ingresado está fuera del rango (1 a 12)");
    }
    printf("Escriba un numero del 1-12:");
    scanf("%i", &num1);

    if (num < 1 || num > 12)
    {
      cumple = 0;
    }
  } while (cumple == 0);
}
```

Comment: C no tiene `bool`, `true` ni `false`. Aparte, ese `scanf( "%i", num1 )` no me termina de convencer. Ni esa comprobación usando `num` ...

Comment: Actualicé el código, ¿qué tal ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores en el código, en el scanf debes escribirlo así:

```
scanf("%i", &num1);
```

y debes cerrar correctamente las llaves de apertura del bucle for.
Aparte, no tiene sentido ese bucle for, te muestro un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int pedir_num(){
        int num1 = 0; //inicializamos la variable 

        printf("Escriba un número del 1-12\n");
        scanf("%i", &num1);
//mientras el número no esté en el rango nos lo volverá a pedir otra vez
        while(num1 < 1 || num1 > 12){ 
            printf("Error: Introduzca en el rango correcto\n");
            scanf("%i", &num1);
        }
        return num1;
    }


    int main() {

        pedir_num();

    return 0;
    }
```